# Moviepy - NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_duration - I cannot figure out why my clip is returning None - what am I missing?

Tags: python, moviepy

I would just like to make a 5 second clip of text animating over a white image, Once i understand this, i can further my project.  but this basic step is holding me back, why am i getting this error ?

I expected a 5 second mp4 and got
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_duration

```
from moviepy.editor import *
import numpy as np

# Create a white image of size (1960, 1080)
img = np.ones((1960, 1080, 3)) * 255

# Define the text and animation
text = "My Super Awesome Text"
clip = TextClip(text, font='Arial.ttf', fontsize=24, color='black')
clip = clip.set_pos('center').set_duration(5)

# Overlay text on the image
final = CompositeVideoClip([img, clip])

# Save animation as mp4
final.write_videofile("/Users/name/Desktop/animation.mp4", fps=1)`
```

Answer (score 1):

You wrote

```
clip = clip.set_pos('center').set_duration(5)
```

expecting a fluent API.
That is, you were hoping each set call would return a clip object.

Given that in this API we instead evaluate for side effects,
with a `None` return value, you will need to phrase it this way:

```
clip.set_position('center')
clip = clip.set_duration(5)
```

Referring to the
[documentation](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/ref/VideoClip/VideoClip.html),
we find that you chose to use an old identifier spelling:

> The function set_pos is deprecated

and in the example that is offered we evaluate for side effects:

> ```
> >>> clip.set_position((45, 150)) ...
> ```

---

Consider updating to moviepy 2.0.
(I don't see it in pypi, yet.)
The `with_` form of the API may be more to your liking.

https://moviepy-tburrows13.readthedocs.io/en/improve-docs/updating_to_v2.html#renamings

> most significant change has been renaming all `.set_` methods to `.with_`. ... they do not modify the clip that they are applied to, instead returning a modified copy of the clip.

Comment: hey! thanks for the quick response, i am now getting the error "TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object" maybe there is something wrong with the clip? is it not being created ?

Comment: You don't _have_ to offer a [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), if you prefer that we make guesses.